# Firefox SQLite Manager to create database for iOS

Tags: firefox, sqlite, sqlitemanager

The default number of rows in a table created by Firefox SQLite Manager is 20.

But I want to insert 50 records in my table.

Where do I have to make changes in SQLite Manager to increase the Number rows?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of Sqlite tables, is that they were not limited to a maximum number of rows?  Are you talking about just only being able to see 20 rows?

That being said, I had some mixed results with the Firefox Sqlite editor (bugs).

As a recommendation I cannot recommend enough the free program SQLite Expert Personal.  It is by FAR the most polished and bug free sqlite editor I have found so far.

http://www.sqliteexpert.com/download.html